# Air for iOS: Testing swipe gesture on my mac

Tags: ios, air, gesture, swipe

I'm working right now on an iOS project with air. Everything is fine, and I implemented the "swipe" gesture among some others. In the beginning, the gesture was recognized, the event fired, everything alright.

Then I changed something (don't ask me what), and the event isn't any more dispatched.

So my Problem is, if I want to test it, I'll have to compile, then upload to testflightapp.com, then install it. Takes a lot of time.

Is there any possibility to test the gesture on my mac while developing? So I can trace and check what is happening, or what not.

I compile with the Flash IDE CS5.5, but could also with Flash Builder if there is a solution.

And just for your interest, here the interesting part of my code.

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
contestView.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE , onSwipeContest);


function onSwipeContest (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{

     if (e.offsetX == 1) { 
      //User swiped towards right
      // do something
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a lame answer, but why aren't you skipping the testflight step and just dumping it straight to your phone? do you have xcode installed? if so, fire it up, open the organizer, set your device for development, and have at it. way, way faster that way.

anyway.

are you sure that gesture events aren't functioning on your mac? i've found that multitouch events are spotty, but gesture ones usually work ok on the trackpad from air 2 onward.

Comment: specifically, here it states that you can test gesture events on the mac:  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/multitouch_gestures.html